# Wicket invalidateNow() deletes other session cookies

Tags: cookies, wicket, session-cookies, jsessionid, wicket-6

I'm running Wicket 6.15, and I've noticed weird behavior when invalidating the user's session.

Upon calling `WebSession.get().invalidateNow()`, I'm expecting `JSESSIONID` session cookie to get deleted.

I've noticed that `JSESSIONID` indeed gets deleted by getting an http response header that sets the cookie's expiry to 0.

I've noticed that this is not limited to the `JSESSIONID`, but it also deletes all other session cookies.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that `WebSession.get().invalidateNow()` only deletes `JSESSIONID` cookie, and leaves other session cookies intact?

Comment: I wouldn't call that behaviour "weird", I'd rather call it "correct". If you're invalidating the session, you want to invalidate all data tied to a session. The question is: what is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Wicket doesn't manage JSESSIONID, nor any other cookie created by application. `Session#invalidate()` and `Session#invalidateNow()` just delegate to `javax.servlet.HttpSession#invalidate()` method, i.e. the web container manages JSESSIONID.